# Предложить открыть веб-страницу при подключении к Wi-Fi

Tags: android, wifi

Как реализовать, чтобы при подключении к Wi-Fi происходило требование на открытие сайта? 
В целом, как реализуются системы с требованием подтверждения пользователя?
Возможно ли реализовать это, используя точку доступа андроида?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понятно при чем тут файлы, если просто при подключении к WiFi  открывать страницу, то это  называется captive portal,  реализован ли сервер  под андроид - не знаю. 
Логика работы довольно простая:  клиент,  подключившись в  WiFi  проверяет а может ли он открыть файл (для  Андроид вот такой http://google.com/generate_204 ), если может, то  не требуется ввода пароля, если не может, то  смотрит код ответа ( должно быть  302 или 511 ) и указание куда далее.